# A dedicated datapath in vhdl for the image below

Tags: vhdl

[image: a dedicated datapath to do addition]

I have been working on this, below is my code. I cant figure out why the counter is not passing its output to the fulladder.

```
entity main is
    port(   
                clock: in std_logic;                                        --clock
                WE: IN std_logic;                                          --write enable
                WA: IN std_logic_vector(1 DOWNTO 0);                --write address
                RAE: IN std_logic;                                      --read enable ports A & B
                RAA: IN std_logic_vector(1 DOWNTO 0);           --read address port A & B
                --PortA: OUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);        --output port A & B
                --Clock: IN STD_LOGIC;
                Number: in std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
                --Clock: in std_logic;
                --Load: in std_logic;
                Reset: in std_logic;        -- counter output
             --A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
             --B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
                --sum : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
               Cout : out STD_LOGIC;
                X: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
                Y: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
                xeqy: out std_logic;
                D: IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0) := ;                 --input
                --E: IN std_logic;
                --D: IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
                OUTPUT: out std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0)
        );
end main;

architecture Behavioral of main is

        component counter is
            Port(
                 Number: in std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
                Clock: in std_logic;
                --Load: in std_logic;
                Reset: in std_logic;
                Output: out std_logic_vector(0 to 7) );
        end component;

        component comp_8bit is
            port(
                X: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
                Y: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";               
                xeqy, xlty, xgty: out std_logic
            );
        end component;



        component fullAdder is
            Port(
                 A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
                 B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
                 sum : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
                 Cout : out STD_LOGIC);
        end component;

        component regfile port
        (
                clock: IN std_logic;                       --clock
                WE: IN std_logic;                          --write enable
                WA: IN std_logic_vector(1 DOWNTO 0);       --write address
                D: IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);        --input
                RAE: IN std_logic;                               --read enable ports A 
                RAA: IN std_logic_vector(1 DOWNTO 0);        --read address port A 
                PortA: OUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0)    --output port A 
        );
        end component;

        component TriStateBuffer port
        (
            E: IN std_logic;
            D: IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
            OUTPUT: OUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0)
        );
        end component;

        signal n: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        signal l: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        signal o: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
        signal m,t: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);


    begin

                U1 : Counter port map (Number, Clock, Reset,m);
                t <= m;
                U2 : comp_8bit port map (t, Y, xeqy);
                U4 : regfile port map (clock, WE, WA, n, RAE, RAA, l );
                U3 : fullAdder port map (l, t, n, Cout );

                U5 : TriStateBuffer port map (E, l,OUTPUT);
                Output <= t;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Please reformat your code!

Comment: Chapter 9, 'Digital Logic and Microprocessor Design with VHDL', Enoch O. Hwang, ISBN 0-534-46593-5. Your code only bears a faint resemblance to Figure 9.19, there is at least one syntax error, it's not possible to aid in debugging without the entity/architectures for counter, comp_8bit, fulladder, regfile and tristate buffer. Your superfluous renaming is confusing and there appear to be connectivity discrepancies between the figure and your code.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

1. This style of component instantiation is very hard to debug. You should stay away from that. Stick with the more commonly used **PORT_NAME => signal;** approach
2. The code should not even compile. For example in the TriStateBuffer instantiation, the signal E input does not even exist with the main entity.
3. The output of the counter is indeed connected to the input of the FullAdder, because you have the **t <= m;** assignment. I just don't understand why you didn't use m directly in the input to the FullAdder
4. The code is an approximation to the picture. But it is still lacking some things such as the Load inputs.

Please clarify.

Although this is not an answer per se, I could not put a comment because I do not have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I was actually wrong and after some more reading i was able to fix the issue i was having. once again thanks for your help